# Invalid cursor exception in java when I am returning an object

Tags: java, database, dataset

I am unable to figure out some small issue that is there in my code. I am having a method that is returning multiple flags from a stored procedure.

Here is my code:

```
// QueryDataSet qds;
Object[] flags = null;

flags = (Call to a stored procedure that is returning multiple result sets)

if(flags != null)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < flags.length; i++)
   {
       qds = ((QueryDataSet)flags[i]);

       if(qds != null)
       {
            int result = qds.getRecord(0).getValue(1).asInt();
            if(result>0)  booleanflags[i]=true;
       }
   }
}

// getValue implementation is returning type of Record and getValue takes in the columnIndex. The stored procedure is returning multiple records and only one column and I am trying to check the count. If greater that 1 then return true else false.
// I am using the debugger and see that the first time in the loop the value is returned fine but when i=1 then it returns Invalid cursor position.
```

Comment: what type of objects are `flags`?  Why would it be cast to a `QueryDataSet`?

Comment: Flags has integer Objects but since my stored Proc can only return Object[] array I am trying to convert the object array

Comment: But what is a QueryDataSet?

Comment: It is a type that has been defined in my project. It is a layer on tip of java.sql.ResultSet i guess. Does this help?

Comment: On fetching records from a select clause we can get individual records and columns as in the database

Comment: so as a set contains the whole set of the results why would you do this within a loop?  Once only should be enough.

Comment: The reason for the loop is my store procedure has MultiResultSet(By this I mean there are multiple selects in a stored Procedure so they are displayed as separate result sets). For example: My stored Proc is returning results from select * from employee and select * from Organization. I want to treat all these as separate records and iterate.